# load src of images that attachs in wordpress's post

Tags: theme-development

I want use these code to load src of images that attachs in wordpress's post:

```
$recent = new WP_Query("showposts=30"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();

        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array(80,80) );
        echo $thumb[0];

endwhile;
```

but my code don't work, and give me nothing.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

The following line is incorrect as `showposts` is deprecated.

```
$recent = new WP_Query("showposts=30");
```

Instead use,

```
$recent = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=30');
```

Following that,

Does the thumbnail size of 80x80 exist?

```
array(80,80)
```

If not try any of,

```
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), small );
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), medium );
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), large );
```

Remember each of small, medium or large - refers to different filenames or `src` - so if you want to retrieve the full resolution image, original upload then use `large`.

If you must return the `src` URL as

```
http://domain.com/image_80x_80x.jpg //example
```

...meaning that you definitely want the 80x80 version and it does not exist then you will need to regenerate your thumbnails.

You can use: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

If you did not add the image size of 80x80 to your theme you can do so using the [`add_image_size`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) function in your functions.php file,

```
add_image_size( 'my_custom_size', 80, 80 );
```

Now, when uploading new images, you will also get a 80x80 version. You can then refer to it as mentioned above by either,

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, array(80,80) ); //via array specifying pixel w & h
```

or

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, my_custom_size ); //via name used in add_image_size
```

Comment: thanks but new code don't work